# How can I search for an iTunes App Store app by SKU?

Tags: itunes

I'm getting some strange results in my LinkShare affiliate report for sales made through the iTunes Store App Store: multiple sales of the same SKU but for different Sales amounts. I'm not aware of any sales on that item, so I'm wondering if someone else happened to pick the same SKU. (That's awfully coincidental b/c this SKU is 1/2 of the total items we've sold.)

So, I'm wondering how I can search for what products have that SKU.

I tried searching the iTunes store for the sku. I didn't get any hits (not surprisingly).

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

Take your SKU (it should be something like..  id398157641 or 398157641)

Pop it in where the same number is.. and make sure there is the word id before it.. like so...

**http://itunes.apple.com/app/app-name/id398157641**